# Retrieving data through Callback

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, callback

I am trying to retrieve the custom username the user on my app sets for themselves from my Firebase Database. I have some code in place that is functioning properly, but I do not know exactly what to set my `TextView` equal to in order to get the data the code is retrieving.

So here is the method that goes and gets the username from my Firebase Database.

```
public void getUser(final MyCallback callback) {
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(uid).child("userName").getValue(User.class);
            if (null!=callback) callback.onSuccess(user);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

And then I have an interface that deals with the callback

```
public interface MyCallback{
    void onSuccess(User user);
}
```

And then finally I call the `getUser()` void where I want the username displayed through this code.

```
final TextView navuserName = findViewById(R.id.navUsername);
getUser(new MyCallback() {
    @Override public void onSuccess(User u) {
        navuserName.setText("hello");
    }
});
```

And where `navuserName.setText("hello");` is, I want that to display the username. But I do not know what to put between the brackets in order to get the `String` that the `getUser()` void is retrieving.

This is how my database is setup

```
{"BP07KgV4yHa0bqpt740kuFzJQGI2" : {
"email" : "sampleEmail@gmail.com",
"userName" : "testUsername"
```

Comment: What's the definition of the `User` type? Is it some type you defined yourself, or is it part of a library? Isn't this merely a matter of replacing `"hello"` with something like `u.getUsername()`, provided that the `User` type defines a `getUsername()` method?

Comment: The problem with doing navuserName.setText(u.getUsername()); is that it I'm supposed to pass a callback in getUsername(  callback   )     but I'm not sure what to really put there

Comment: Please update your question to show what data you have at `myRef/Users/uid/userName` (as text, no screenshot please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Got an example of the setup there

Answer (score 0):

In your User class you need getter and setter for your field, in this case, user name.
Add them like this to the String variable that you use to store user name in your User class:

```
private String username; 

public String getusername()
{

    return this.username;
}
public void setusername(String value)
{

     this.username= value;
}
// If you don't want User class to be initialized without passing a user name then you can add user name to it's constructor 

public class User ( String username )
{
   this.username = username;
}
```

To get user from Firebase you should refer to all data in this case uid node. But if you only want to get the user name then you should use it like this:

```
  User user = new User();
String username;
username = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(uid).child("userName").getValue();
user.setusername(username);
```

And to retrieve the  data in order to pass to the TextView use user.getusername()

Comment: I have been trying this method and tweaking it a lot but I keep coming back to this issue. The line where username is set to dataSnapshot... gives me the issue that username is a String and is being set to a User object so it won't allow it. I have tried replacing username with 'user' and then doing setusername(user.getusername) but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: You have to do casting, I edited my answer please check it out again. And if my answer helped don't forget to click check mark on left top of my answer.

Comment: That is starting to work better. You are helping me make a lot of progress so thank you!! My issue now is I get a null reference error on the dataSnapshot. I have dataSnapshot defined so I am not entirely sure why this error is happening. The pathing is correct too.